# FullCalendar adding data-date at tbody td on the div with a class of fc-content-skeleton

Tags: fullcalendar

Can I add `date-add` at the tbody td of the div with class `fc-content-skeleton` table? coz only the thead td has a `data-date`, can we data-date at it also?

Comment: I guess you could, if you modified the source code of fullCalendar. But I'd be interested to know why you think you need to do this? Perhaps there is another way to achieve your actual goal, if you can explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky, but here's one way to do it.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv71on5y/).

Fullcalendar has several callbacks where you can execute arbitrary Javascript.  So you can use one of those callbacks to iterate over all the elements you want and add the data attributes you want.

I used the `eventAfterAllRender` callback below.  Initially I tried using the (more logically suitable) `viewRender` callback, but it seems the `tbody td` elements do not actually exist at that point, so you can't find or modify them.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {

        var row, cell, date;

        // First iterate over each calendar row
        $('.fc-content-skeleton').each(function(i) {
            row = $(this);

            // Now iterate over each header cell within this row
            $('thead td', row).each(function(k) {
                cell = $(this);

                // Get the date attribute from the current thead td
                date = cell.data('date');

                // Find the matching tbody td, at the same index 'k'
                // as our current thead td, and add the data attribute.
                $('tbody td', row).eq(k).data('date', date);

                // Since the data attribute won't be visible in the source, 
                // temporarily add the actual date to the cell to confirm
                // it is really working.  Remove this once you can see it works.
                $('tbody td', row).eq(k).html(date);
            });
        });
    }
});
```